# Keep hyperlink to specific word in UITextView using attributedString

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, nsattributedstring

I'm trying to implement an editor that can handle hashtag while typing.

```
extension UITextView {

func resolveHashTags() {
    if self.text.isEmpty {
        let emptyString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: " ", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.black,
                                                                              NSAttributedString.Key.font: self.font!])
        self.attributedText = emptyString
        self.textColor = .black
        self.text = ""
        return
    }
    let cursorRange = selectedRange
    let nsText = NSString(string: self.text)
    let words = nsText.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet(charactersIn: "@#ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789_").inverted).filter({!$0.isEmpty})

    self.textColor = .black
    let attrString = NSMutableAttributedString()
    attrString.setAttributedString(self.attributedText)
    attrString.addAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor.black], range: nsText.range(of: self.text))
    
    var anchor: Int = 0

    for word in words {

        // found a word that is prepended by a hashtag!
        // homework for you: implement @mentions here too.
        let matchRange:NSRange = nsText.range(of: word as String, range: NSRange(location: anchor, length: nsText.length - anchor))
        anchor = matchRange.location + matchRange.length
        if word.hasPrefix("#") {

            // a range is the character position, followed by how many characters are in the word.
            // we need this because we staple the "href" to this range.
            

            // drop the hashtag
            let stringifiedWord = word.dropFirst()
            if let firstChar = stringifiedWord.unicodeScalars.first, NSCharacterSet.decimalDigits.contains(firstChar) {
                // hashtag contains a number, like "#1"
                // so don't make it clickable
            } else {
                // set a link for when the user clicks on this word.
                // it's not enough to use the word "hash", but you need the url scheme syntax "hash://"
                // note:  since it's a URL now, the color is set to the project's tint color
                attrString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.link, value: "hash:\(stringifiedWord)", range: matchRange)
            }

        } else if !word.hasPrefix("@") {
            
        }
    }
    self.attributedText = attrString
    self.selectedRange = cursorRange
}
}
```

So this is the extension I'm using to create a hyperlink in UITextView. Called in `func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView)`

So while typing if any word starts with `#`. It'll turn in hyperlinks and will change color to blue. After typing the intended word if you press space it goes back to black text. This is expected behavior. [image]

But if you clear text and move your course back to hashtag word like this [image]

it keeps extending hyperlink to the next word too.[image]

any solution to keep hyperlinks to that word only. Anything typed after hashtag should be normal text

Comment: `// so don't make it clickable`: Then remove the `.link` attribute, just in case?, or in the `else` after  `} else if !word.hasPrefix("@") { ... } else { removeLinkIfThereWasOne }`? If your code, where was analyzed "asd", where did it passed? What were its attributes then?

Comment: This is the only play textview's attributedString is generated

Comment: I need to make it a link. Because I have stored some extra properties in it which I need once the user types everything.

Comment: There are some cases in which I need to make multiple words a link. My only problem is that on first-time text goes back to normal when typed space. But going back to the linked word it extends it.

Comment: What I'm saying, is that when you starting retyping, it's keeping the `.link` to the new text, so you need to remove it. In all your `else` cases, remove `.link` attribute. So do it in the else, or just, after `attrString.setAttributedString(self.attributedText)`: `attrString.removeAttribute(.link, range: _NSRange(location: 0, length: attrString.length))`.

Comment: @Larme As I said there are cases in which multiple words are HyperLinked so it removed links from later words too. These multiple words links are for mention which starts with @.

Comment: But since you are iterating again with `for word in words {}`, you are doing it all again. So you'll add all again the links for # and @ words. So `attrString.removeAttribute(.link, range: _NSRange(location: 0, length: attrString.length))` just after `attrString.setAttributedString(self.attributedText)` doesn't work? Did you try at least?

Comment: mentions are added from another place. But should be kept as it is.  Which it doesn't. I tried your solution and it keeps link to one word only. For mention if it's multiple word it losses hyperlink

Comment: So, as said previously, `if word.hasPrefix("#") { if let firstChar = ... {... } else { attrString.removeAttribute(.link, range: matchRange) }  } else if !word.hasPrefix("@") { attrString.removeAttribute(.link, range: matchRange) }` should work.

Comment: Did you not get the point about link with multiple words. 2nd word will loose hyperlink with this solution.

Comment: No because, I would have thought that mention was with only one word (since you iterate over words). If it's just with hash, then remove all the `hash://` before hand. But I guess you'll have that issue also with mentions and others by going back to the text? I would just redo all the mention/hash linking again.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out.

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    var shouldReturn = true
    let selectedRange = textView.selectedRange
    let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: textView.attributedText)
    if !text.isEmpty && text != " " {
        var userAttributes = [(NSAttributedString.Key, Any, NSRange)]()
        attributedText.enumerateAttribute(.link, in: _NSRange(location: 0, length: textView.text.count), options: .longestEffectiveRangeNotRequired) { (value, range, stop) in
            if let url = value as? String, url.hasPrefix("user:") {
                userAttributes.append((.link, value!, range))
            }
        }
        if let userLink = userAttributes.first(where: {$0.2.contains(range.location - 1)}) {
            attributedText.replaceCharacters(in: range, with: NSAttributedString(string: text, attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.link : userLink.1, NSAttributedString.Key.font : textView.font as Any]))
            textView.attributedText = attributedText
            shouldReturn = false
        } else {
            attributedText.replaceCharacters(in: range, with: NSAttributedString(string: text, attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font : textView.font as Any]))
            textView.attributedText = attributedText
            textDidChange?(textView)
            shouldReturn = false
        }
        textView.selectedRange = _NSRange(location: selectedRange.location + text.count, length: 0)
        textViewDidChange(textView)
    }
    return shouldReturn
}
```

This way I have the control to update the link in between the word and it doesn't extend afterward to a new word.